# Handling one form divided in multiple pages with one servlet

Tags: forms, jsp, servlets

is it possible to process one form divided into multiple pages with one servlet?

For example:

page1.jsp

```
<form action="FormServlet" method="post">
<table>
<tr><td>Field1 :</td><td><input type="text" name="login"/></td></tr>
<tr><td>Field2 :</td><td><input type="password" name="password"/></td></tr>
<tr><td>Field3 :</td><td><input type="password" name="password"/></td></tr>
<tr><td>Field4 :</td><td><input type="password" name="password"/></td></tr>
<tr><td>Field5 :</td><td><input type="password" name="password"/></td></tr>
<tr><td>Field6 :</td><td><input type="password" name="password"/></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="lossdetails.jsp">Next</a></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

lossdetails.jsp

```
<form action="LoginServlet" method="post">
<table>
<tr><td>Field1 :</td><td><input type="text" name="login"/></td></tr>
<tr><td>Field2 :</td><td><input type="text" name="login"/></td></tr>
<tr><td>Field4 :</td><td><input type="text" name="login"/></td></tr>
<tr><td>Field5 :</td><td><input type="password" name="password"/></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="submit" name="Login" value="Submit FNOB"/></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Any ideas? 
Thanks 
Servo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your html i hope you need wizard like submit, Once the first wizard completed then save it and go for next. Have you looked this? [Smart Wizard](http://mstratman.github.io/jQuery-Smart-Wizard/). This may helps you.